# super init with data error

Tags: swift, swift3, initialization

I have a convenience initializer that calls onto an initializer that calls onto a super class initializer with header `init!(data: Data!)`. What I don't understand is why I am getting the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I have tried initializing a random `Data` object with no data but I still obtain this error any ideas?

Code:

```
Convenience init(itemId: String) {
    let d: Data = Data.init()
    self.init(data: d) // error here!
}

required init!(data: Data?) {
    super.init(data: data)
}
```

super class from obj c library:

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSData*)data {
    if ([self init]) {
       //some code
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What's the superclass's code?

Comment: @BallpointBen the super class is a class coming from an objective c file, i have added the header for it

Comment: Is it possible to view the generated swift interface for the obj c file?

Comment: You can do that in Xcode by cmd + clicking on the symbol (such as the class name). It should take you to the generated interface rather than the source.

Comment: @BallpointBen thank you for your help! I updated my answer, however is as Allen Humphreys said its returning a nil thats why when it comes back it gives me an error, thank you again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [implicitly unwrapped optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) parameters and initializers. If you'd like to have a failable initializer, you should use `init?` instead. As for passing in an argument that is implicitly unwrapped. That is really dangerous, too. Marking things as implicitly unwrapped is very convenient for avoiding the Swift compiler complaining, but it will often lead to this problem.

The problem is your call to `super.init` is returning `nil`.

This example shows you a safe way to do failable initialization.

```
// This is a stand in for what your super class is doing
// Though I can't tell you why it is returning nil
class ClassB {
    required init?(data: Data?) {
        return nil
    }
}

class ClassA: ClassB {
    convenience init?(itemId: String) {
        let d: Data = Data.init()
        self.init(data: d) // error here!
    }

    required init?(data: Data?) {
        super.init(data: data)
    }
}

if let myObject = ClassA.init(itemId: "ABC") {
    // non-nil
} else {
    // failable initializer failed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was tricky but you got it! Thank you again my issue has been solved!